# How to fetch all the data from the contacts in a Windows Phone app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to have the names and pictures of all the contacts and store it somewhere? How can we do that? From what I have found, it is only allowing to search for one and get its details.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with a reading on [Contact filtering and matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286417%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in msdn. For code snippet, check [How to access contact data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

For example a sample from msdn to count this items :

```
private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with the results.
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
}
```

Don't forget to add the `ID_CAP_CONTACTS` capability in your app's manifest and a `using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;` to your code.

Update :

For example if you want every name of your contacts :

```
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = e.Results; //Here your result
    string everynames = String.Empty;
    foreach (var item in contacts)
    {
        //We can get attributes from each item
        everynames += item.DisplayName +  Environment.NewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(everynames);
}
```

Update 2 :

For example if you want name, first mail and first number, you could use a code like this :

```
    void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = e.Results; //Here your result
        string everynames = String.Empty;
        foreach (var item in contacts)
        {
            //We can get attributes from each item
            everynames += item.DisplayName + ";" //Get name
                + (item.EmailAddresses.Count() > 0 ? (item.EmailAddresses.FirstOrDefault()).EmailAddress : "") + ";" //Check if contact has an email. If so, display it. He can be more than one !
                + (item.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0 ? (item.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()).PhoneNumber : "") + ";" //Check if contact has a phonenumber. If so, display it. He can be more than one !
                + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(everynames);
    }
```

Update 3 :

If you want all pictures, I will share you an example. Don't forget to check the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.userdata.contact.getpicture%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) :

```
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
        foreach (var result in e.Results)
        {
            var stream = result.GetPicture();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(stream); // You can do a list of image if you want to.
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = bmp;
                stack.Children.Add(img); // I choose to display in a stackpanel
            }
        }
}
```

Don't forget to try {} catch {}
You can change `FilterKind` in `SearchAsync()`. We use `FilterKind.None` to get everything.

Comment: Actually I read that example but it does not say anything about fetching all the data at once. Here is a function that allows to do so, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207522(v=vs.105).aspx ?
Can you please give me a sample code which use this?

Comment: in `Contacts_SearchCompleted()` add this line before the `MessageBox` : `var contacts = e.Results;` . Contacts is IEnumerable of Contact. You can access what you want with it.

Comment: I added another example, if you want.

Comment: @user3235018 : the ContactQueryResult.GetContactsAsync() you are trying to use works for the ContactStore object, it won't help you here, I will add this as an update in my answer

Comment: A ContactStore object can be useful. It is specific. I dont really now  what @user3235018 wants to do with this data. If he want to rebuild a control like the native control "people", he should check the ContactStore object.

Comment: Thank You @aloisdg. Can you tell me this as well if we want to get the pictures of those contacts as well, how can we do that? Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can ! You have to use the method `GetPicture()` to do it.

Comment: Glad to help you. Dont forget to marked as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You access Contact Data on WindowsPhone using the `Microsoft.Phone.UserData` namespace, here's a full article about achieving that [How to access contact data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), However if you wanna go little bit further in Creating Contacts, try the [ContactStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactstore%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class it has many methods that help you do what you want.

**Update :**

if you want to get all contacts :

1. First declare `using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;`
2. Use the following code to fire and subscribe to the search :

code :

```
private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    /* Here use the e.Results to return an object of type QueryDataEnumerable<Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact> where you can enumerate through the contacts returned*/
}
```

Using the Asynchronous method SearchAsync with String.empty and FilterKind.None just returns all the contacts you have on your phone it returns an object of type `QueryDataEnumerable<Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contact>` which you can loop through and use each contact separately.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Update 2 :**

the ContactQueryResult.GetContactsAsync() you are trying to use works with the [ContactStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207034%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Class which helps you create a custom contact store for your app. When you save contacts to this store, they will appear on the phone’s People hub, integrated with the user’s other contacts ... (see full article), and I don't think that helps your case, I think using what's already mentioned in this answer , will give you the ability to get all contacts you want, and consume them as you want.

**Update 3 :**

use such a code in the Contacts_SearchCompleted method to get the picture of a contact

```
Stream s = ((Contact)e.Results.First()).GetPicture();
```

Comment: I had read that msdn links but the example given was to search for a contact and then get its details, actually I want to access all the contact details and save them separately.

Comment: I updated my answer, is that what you looking for ??

Comment: I got the names by looping around, can you please tell me how to get the pictures as well? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @AymenDaudi I have put these in the method, var contacts = e.Results; //Here your result string everynames = String.Empty; foreach (var item in contacts) { Stream s = ((Contact)item.First()).GetPicture(); //We can get attributes from each item } But it is saying stream namespace not found, and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable does not conatain definition of first. Basically I need to get picture of each and every contact

Comment: add using System.IO; and replace `(Contact)item.First()` with `item`